# Karate API query part of URL in Path

Tags: karate

query part of API endpoint is unable get the expected result

?name=Active_job this query in endpoint which becomes after execution of scenario %3Fname=Active_job
due to this Testcase is failed

Given path 'admin/rest/activescript/createscript/?name=Active_job'

Please suggest also DDT with this scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `param` and you can do all the DDT you want: https://github.com/intuit/karate#param

```
Given path 'admin/rest/activescript/createscript/'
And param name = 'Active_job'
```